# PHP checking array key content on dynamic arrays

Tags: php

I have an array of data which contains child arrays, each child array can contain a different number of keys:

Example:

Parent array $service:

```
[0] => stdClass Object // 9 keys
(
[std] => 11:47
[etd] => On time
[platform] => 15
[operator] => Southern
[operatorCode] => SN
[serviceType] => train
[length] => 12
[serviceID] => 2R2kKgVAvyBh7d/FhIatXQ==
[rsid] => SN220703
)


[1] => stdClass Object // 7 keys
(
[std] => 11:47
[etd] => On time
[operator] => Southern
[operatorCode] => SN
[serviceType] => train
[serviceID] => OH2Ufaa4ToefjtmYSubfQA==
[rsid] => SN351100
)
```

If I dump the array for $service using:

```
foreach( $service as $index => $obj ){
    $keys=array_keys( get_object_vars( $obj ) );
    print_r ($keys);
}
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => std
    [1] => etd
    [2] => operator
    [3] => operatorCode
    [4] => serviceType
    [5] => length
    [6] => serviceID
    [7] => rsid
    [8] => origin
    [9] => destination
)
Array
(
    [0] => std
    [1] => etd
    [2] => operator
    [3] => operatorCode
    [4] => serviceType
    [5] => serviceID
    [6] => rsid
    [7] => origin
    [8] => destination
)
```

The child arrays both contain a different number of keys, the first contains 10 and the second contain 9.

I then loop through each of the child arrays and write the results to a data table:

```
foreach( $keys as $key ){
    ${$key}=$obj->$key;
    print_r (${$key});
}
```

The issue I have is if the second child array only has 9 keys, in this example "[5] => length" is missing from the second array, 
each successive loop writes the content of the missing key to my data table.

My question is, how can I check if the child arrays contain "[5] => length" before writing to the data table and if not present write nothing to the corresponding data table field.

Complete script:

```
require("../../../../sysscripts/rail/OpenLDBWS.php");
$OpenLDBWS = new OpenLDBWS("my_token");
$data = $OpenLDBWS->GetDepartureBoard(100,"$Station");
header("Content-Type: text/plain");



$results=$data->GetStationBoardResult;
$generatedAt=$results->generatedAt;
$origin_crs=$results->crs;
$message=$results->nrccMessages->message->{'_'};
$platform=$results->platformAvailable;


/* The services... */
$service=$results->trainServices->service;
if( is_array( $service ) ){

    foreach( $service as $index => $obj ){
        $keys=array_keys( get_object_vars( $obj ) );
        print_r ($keys);

        foreach( $keys as $key ){
            ${$key}=$obj->$key;
            //print_r (${$key});
        }

        $origin_location=$origin->location->locationName;
        $generatedAt = date("Y-m-d H:i");
        $dest_location=$destination->location->locationName;
        $crsName=$destination->location->crs;
        $via=$destination->location->via;


        $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO UKRail_departboards (RecordDate, ServiceID, Origin_location, Origin_crs, Platform, ScheduleTime, Estimated, Dest_location, Dest_crs, Operator, Message, IsCancelled, CancelReason, DelayedReason, DeleteCode, NoCarrages, Via, DeleteTime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['RecordDate']= $generatedAt, "date"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['ServiceID'] = $serviceID, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Origin_location'] = $origin_location, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Origin_crs'] = $origin_crs, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Platform'] = $platform, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['ScheduleTime'] = $std, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Estimated'] = $etd, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Dest_location'] = $dest_location, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Dest_crs']= $crsName, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Operator'] = $operator, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Message'] = $message, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['IsCancelled'] = $isCancelled, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['CancelReason'] = $cancelReason, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['DelayedReason'] = $delayReason, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['DeleteCode'] = $DeleteCode, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['NoCarrages'] = $length, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['Via'] = $via, "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['DeleteTime'] = $DeleteTime, "text"));

        mysql_select_db($database_ex, $ex);
        $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $ex) or die(mysql_error());

        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: i might be missing the point, but are you looking for something like http://php.net/count ? this will let you count the amount of elements in the array

Comment: add the last foreach in the first one

Comment: you can make an array of all the keys(hard-coded) and then inside foreach compare with current array keys and which keys are missing add corresponding value form them also

Comment: This would be easy if the entry with key `5` was just missing ... but you have a different value there in your second array, so you would have to check the values and determine their _meaning_ first. Assuming that you know the possible keys/property names beforehand, this would be a lot easier if you didn’t convert the objects to arrays in the first place - then sth. like `isset($obj->length)` will help you determine whether the current object has that property or not ...

Comment: The `array_search()` function search an array for a value and returns the key. eg: `array_search('length',$arrayname);`.

Comment: Or, if you’re hell-bent on working with arrays instead of objects, then cast them to an associative array, so that the property names will become the keys - `(array) $obj` ...

Comment: Use the keys *as they are* to produce an insert, don't pollute the scope with creating variables (`${$key}`). The problem is that you expect some variable to exist (somewhere not shown here), but if a subsequent iteration does not *overwrite* a previous value, you use the previous one. Please show the code that is actually *using* those variables. My bet is that a simple: `$data = array_merge($defaults, (array) $obj);` would suffice.

Comment: Hi all, I had added the complete script to my original question if that helps. many thanks.

Comment: As I expected you *use* the dynamically created variables to produce an insert-statement. **Don't do that**. Instead create an array that holds the data and access it's keys appropriately. You can then use a *fresh* array on each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you face is that if the first object contains the `length` property, but the next does not, then the first iteration of your loop will define the `$length` variable with the given value, but the second iteration of the loop will not touch that variable, i.e. it will still hold the value from the first iteration.

The best way to proceed is to ***not*** create such variables, but to access to the object properties directly. If they don't exist for a given object, you will get a `null` value instead, which is just what you need for your SQL statement.

So, remove this code:

```
    $keys=array_keys( get_object_vars( $obj ) );
    print_r ($keys);

    foreach( $keys as $key ){
        ${$key}=$obj->$key;
        //print_r (${$key});
    }
```

And change the following:

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['NoCarrages'] = $length, "text")
```

to:

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['NoCarrages'] = $obj->length, "text")
```

... repeating this change for all such dynamically created variables.

*Remark*: unrelated to your question, but assigning values to `$_POST` elements goes against the purpose of this array, and moreover, you are overwriting these values in each iteration.

Comment: Hi, if I do as you say I get an error "Cannot access empty property" on line 150 which is "GetSQLValueString($_POST['NoCarrages'] = $obj->$length, "text"),". Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, I did not remove the "$" from $length.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you, then you have

- a list of values represented as key->value pairs ($service)
- a list of keys which are required for processing (which I'll call $required)

To solve the question you asked,

```
$supplied=array_keys($service);
if (count(array_intersect($supplied, $service)) == count($required)) {
    // good to go, ALL the required params are present, there may be extra ones
} else {
    print "Missing attributes:" . implode(",", 
      array_intersect(array_diff($supplied, $service), $supplied)
    );
}
```

However, that ignores the journey that got you to the point of having an array populated only with some named attributes, and any additional validation requirements for validation of the input. A beter solution is to define, an an attribute by attribute basis the requirements for a valid dataset:

```
 $validate=array(
   'std' => '^\d\d:\d\d$|^$',
   'etd' => '(^On time$|^$|^Late$|^Cancelled$)',
   'platform' => '^\d*$',
   ...
 }

 function vaidate_input($service, $validate)
 {
    foreach($validate as $name=>$rgx) {
       if (!preg_match("/$rgx/i", $service[$name])) {
          return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
 }
```

(note that regexes also work in Javascript - so provide a neat way of doing validation in both the front and backend)